# Segmentation Fault In Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm trying to run my application on a Genymotion virtual device , but when installing the application I have encountered

> Segmentation Fault

and  so the app is not running , 
I tried also to drag and drop the .apk into the device after starting it and the following error occurs:

[image]

The Log File : There is warning and drag'n drop mode = off
[image]

Any Help Please!

Comment: Does your emulator work normally otherwise? Did you try the usual uninstall and reinstall of the emulator?

Comment: When I press the menu button it doesn't show anything but the battery and camera buttons works fine , I think the emulator works fine . Yes I did but it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: More questions: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox? Does your computer have these hardware specifications? 
OpenGL 2.0 capable video card, with an up-to-date driver;
VT-x or AMD-V capable CPU, enabled in BIOS settings;

Comment: I've edited my question , there is a warning that says The host CPU does not support HW visualization.

Comment: There's a good chance, if you are on a Windows machine, you have hyper-v enabled. Try turning off hyper-v and then running the emulator. Otherwise try enabling VT-X in your BIOS (if you have an Intel processor).